# Authetication Server advise

Tags: authentication, kerberos, centos7, openldap, samba

I was wondering.. I am setting up a authentication server for our small business as learning opportunity, but it also needs to be functional and usable.
The requirements are:
- Users login on there laptops via this server
- Users login to our NAS (Samba shares)
- Users can login to several services and servers
- I want it to give me a form of access control
- It needs to be linux/CentOS

Now I've read about Kerberos and LDAP but it's just so complicated and I have no idea if it actually does what I want it to..

Has anyone any ideas, suggestions or advise?

Thanks in advance!
Greets,
Thursten

Answer (score 0):

> Now I've read about Kerberos and LDAP but it's just so complicated and
>   I have no idea if it actually does what I want it to.

Indeed, understanding LDAP and Kerberos from scratch can be complicated. Setting what you want from ground up for the first time can be complicated, too. Implementing a solid configuration properly is even more complicated. Maintaining the configuration? Oh, this can be hard, too. :)

To make it easier and to avoid configuration mistakes, you could consider a product such as [Apache Directory / ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/). There should be other similar open-source and free or paid products that implement LDAP and Kerberos. That's in case you must use Linux / CentOS.

Note that Microsoft offers Active Directory as part of Windows Server. Windows Server is a paid product, but Kerberos authentication and directory service works out of the box there and are very easy to deploy (they just work). Just wanted to make a note about that in case you have doubts about Windows vs. Linux -based solution.

Comment: thanks, I will check that out! unfortunately Windows Server is not an option.. I have read something about FreeIPA which seems relatively simple compared to LDAP, any ideas on that?

Comment: @Thursten LDAP is a protocol. Kerberos is a protocol too. These protocols solve different problems. FreeIPA and Apache Directory are products that implement these protocols to support certain use cases and scenarios.